# Can I use ActionBar in a Google infowindow in map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-actionbar

Can I Use **ActionBar** in a [Google Maps **Info window**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows)?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes,I could not find any solution

Comment: `I could not find any solution`... to **what**?

Comment: to use action bar in infowindow,Because of this I asked this question To understand this work is Implementable or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could put a `Toolbar` in whatever `View` you return for the info window contents, if you wanted that look.

But an info window does not respond to any user input, other than a click on the whole window. So, you cannot have toolbar buttons, overflow menus, or the like in the info window.